# How can i retrieve the PONumber

Tags: authorize.net

When I charge a credit card in Authorize.net, along with the `createTransactionRequest`  I send along also a `poNumber`. This appears in the admin portal alongside all transaction details.

But when I retrieve the batches via the API to see what was charged/settled etc., I dont see any `ponumber`

Here is a sample of what I get back

```
<transaction>
<transId>9999</transId>
<submitTimeUTC>2017-12-03T20:16:23Z</submitTimeUTC>
<submitTimeLocal>2017-12-03T15:16:23</submitTimeLocal>
<transactionStatus>declined</transactionStatus>
<invoiceNumber>9999</invoiceNumber>
<accountType>AmericanExpress</accountType>
<accountNumber>XXXX9999</accountNumber>
<settleAmount>50.00</settleAmount>
<marketType>MOTO</marketType>
<product>Card Not Present</product>
</transaction>
```

Is there any way to get back the `poNumber` as well? It is very important for me.

PS. I don't need specifically the `ponumber`, any arbitrary field/tag would be fine for me.

Thanks

Comment: Authorize.Net is not a data store. You shouldn't be using it to store your data. This information should be kept in a database so you can easily retrieve it whenever you want to (and quicker, too).

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the delay. This is a specific client request. I must store an additional key/id with each payment, in case it doesnt commit properly to the database. 99% of the time it's saved properly and there's no issue. This is a fallback for the 1%. Thanks